# How to use a variable for running count down timer?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I was creating a timer app and I wanted to use CountdownTimer on Android Studio with a variable . It was showing no error , but on run-time it is (CountdownTimer) running only one time.

```
  int set=1;
    final long totalTime=(hour*60)+min;


    if(set==1){

        new CountDownTimer(totalTime , 1000){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                long min=millisUntilFinished/1000;

                Log.i("Remaining time", String.valueOf(min));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {



            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: Shouldn't totalTime also be in ms?

Comment: yes! that was the mistake, my bad. LOL

Answer (score 0):

May be if you pass totalTime in ms like..

```
final long totalTime=(hour*60)+min;  //In min convert to ms

long totalTimeInMs = ((hour*60)+min)*60*1000)

 new CountDownTimer(totalTimeInMs , 1000){

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            long second = millisUntilFinished/1000;

            long min = millisUntilFinished/60;

            Log.i("Remaining time", String.valueOf(min));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {



        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

`CountDownTimer` ctor expects two time intervals `millisInFuture` and `countDownInterval`, both in **milliseconds**. So:

```
final long totalTimeInMinutes=(hour*60)+min;
final long totalTime=totalTimeInMinutes * 60 * 1000;
```